# Trivia doubts in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have 2 very basic doubts about Unix.

1) Why the Unix default file creation permission mode is **666** where as for a directory it is **777**? Why it should not be 777 also?

2) In what way these following commands differ from each other?

```
cat filename
cat < filename
```

I know that the latter one is using input redirection, but how the behavior is getting changed is what my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case the mode *777* sets the executable bit of a file (in case of directory it basically allows stepping in to look at contents)

In the latter question the two commands do similar thing by different means:

- First command *opens and reads file* `filename` and outputs its contents
- Second command reads *standard input* (into which `shell` pipes the contents of `filename`) and outputs it (contents) out. In this case `cat` has no idea it is operating on `filename`.